# import modules that come with anaconda when running jupyter notebook within tensorflow virtualenv

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow. I have successfully installed tensorflow in anaconda on Ubuntu linux running over vmware on my laptop. In my tensorflow virtualenv, I installed and launched jupyter notebook. 
My question is how I can import those python modules in anaconda when I'm running jupyter notebook from tensorflow virtual environment? I always got import errors.
When I launch jupyter notebook in normal mode, everything seems to be OK.

Below are the steps I followed to install tensorflow in anaconda:

```
1. conda create -n tensorflow3 python=3.5
2. wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.8.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
3. mv tensorflow-0.8.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl tensorflow-0.8.0rc0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl
4. source activate tensorflow
5. pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-0.8.0rc0-py3-none-linux_x86_64.whl
6. conda install ipython
7. conda install jupyter
```

Now I launched jupyter notebook from the virtual environment. When I tried to import matplotlib, scipy or sklearn, I got error messages like: **`no module named xxxx`**

Comment: Virtual environments are completely isolated from the rest. You have to install all packages you want to use into the enviroment. Try installing them with conda.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer.  Just wondering what is the best way to install all the preinstalled packages in anaconda on my tensorflow virtualenv?

Comment: if you want the full anaconda set of packages, `conda install anaconda=4` should do

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much!